# Call to undefined method user::get_articles()

Tags: php, undefined-function

I'm pretty new to PHP and was doing fine until I hit this brick wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Actually, it was a simple miscommunication issue with my partner... he changed the directory structure without me knowing which resulted in this issue. This question may be considered closed. Thank you for all your help.

I have a class user() in which I created this get_articles() public function:

```
public function get_articles($obj_user){
        try
        {
            $loc_dbo = $obj_user->connect();

            $query = "CALL VIEW_MEMBER_ARTICLES(:in_var1)";
            $stmt = $loc_dbo->prepare($query);

            $stmt->bindParam(':in_var1',$obj_user->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $result = $stmt->execute();

            if($result)
            {
                $arrArticles = array();
                $index=0; //INDEX OF ROW IN ARRAY
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    //ADDING DATA TO A TWO-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
                    //NAMED COLUMNS
                    $arrArticles[$index] = array();
                    $arrArticles[$index]['mem_user_name']=$row['mem_user_name'];
                    $arrArticles[$index]['article_post_date']=$row['article_post_date'];
                    $arrArticles[$index]['lvl_short_desc']=$row['lvl_short_desc'];
                    $arrArticles[$index]['article_subject']=$row['article_subject'];
                    $arrArticles[$index]['article_body']=$row['article_body'];
                    $arrArticles[$index]['pic_URL']=$row['pic_URL'];

                    $index++; //INCREMENT ROW INDEX COUNTER
                }
            $stmt->closeCursor(); //releases the bdd connection for another query.
            return $arrArticles; //RETURNS THE ARRAY CONTAINING ARTICLES
            }
            else
            {
                return "Query Failed!";
            }
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

From a page in which I have included my user class file, I'm calling this function like so:

```
            $arr_posts = $p_user->get_articles($p_user);

                for ($row = 0; $row < count($arr_posts); $row++)
                {
                    for ($col = 0; $col < 6; $col++) 
                    {
                    echo "<tr class=\"".active."\">";
                    echo "<td>\"".$row."\"</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$arr_posts[$row]['article_post_date']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$arr_art[$row]['article_subject']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."2"."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
            }
```

$p_user is declared at the top of the page, as a new user(). I just can't understand why I'm getting an error saying the method is undefined.

Comment: This isn't how OOP is meant to work: `$p_user->get_articles($p_user);`. You don't have to pass the object in, the target of a method invocation is always available inside the method as `$this`.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response. Although I now understand that the invocation is available with $this... it hasn't fixed my problem with the undefined method.

Comment: It was commentary, not an answer to your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that there aren't 2 class called "User"? You are not using autoload, are you? Try var_dump($p_user)

Comment: Thank you, nonetheless - your comment has taught me something new and that is always worth something. I'm implementing this change in my code as we speak.

Comment: only one class user is defined... and I call other functions within it throughout my code, without problems. This is the only function which gives me errors. Thank you for your response estshy. I will try dumping the variable and let you know what happens

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, so I'll put it here. I've figured out the problem and all is resolved. My partner changed the folder structure without telling me resulting in this error. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folders were simply misplaced by an associate. Closed.